# select multiple table but one of table didn't any value sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 table I want to show all table but if one of table didn't have value still showing 
can show all table with condition like that using join query?

table karyawan

[image]

table absen

[image]

I want to still join like this if table absen didn't have value

[image]

Comment: could you provide us what have you tried

Comment: You either need a simple left /right join, or a simulation of a full outer join.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from  karyawan a full outer join absen b on a.id_kar=b.id_kar
```

Comment: Code is always better with an explanation  of what it does.

Comment: full join don't support in mysql